# Create Normal Distribution curve in Excel

Tags: excel, statistics

Trying to draw a Bell Curve/Normal Distribution curve with the data set provided, but it is not getting created on Excel. Can anyone help me in creating the same.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ipDo6WlbmDUBZuuS4ya3ZGD7mkP_vnbByK3KvyLbJ88/edit?usp=sharing

The above file can be used as the data set for creating the curve. Can someone explain me the procedure of how to make a curve with the above data set in Excel?

Comment: [How to Make a Bell Curve in Excel (Step-by-step Guide)](https://trumpexcel.com/bell-curve/).

Comment: Thank you for the guide. I'd surely check on this.

Answer (score 0):

if your data is normally distributed it should resemble a bell curve.

By "Trying to draw a Bell Curve/Normal Distribution curve", are you referring to a line diagram?

Remember, the bell curve is a histogram of your data. If you inserted a histogram of your data, would that be enough?

If not, what you could do is calculate the standard deviation of your data (and the mean), then you could make a column for different standard deviations and what value we expect it to be.

We could then incorporate that into your old histogram. You could use a "Combo" chart and plot the histogram on one axis and the a line for your calculated values (you can make it smooth if you think it's too sharp. Also, you could decrease the distance between each of your calculated values (1.1, 1.2, ...) instead of let's say halves of standard deviations.

Unfortunately, the data you provided is not at all normally distributed.

[image]

***So you can't create a bell curve based on this data, no.***

Comment: I wanted to inform you that I have no clue on how to Normalize the data. Can we normalize this data and if yes, what is the methodology. You just downvoted my question I can understand because I wasn't clear on my ask. Please let me know if you need anything further.

Comment: Hi, I did *not* down-vote your question, someone else did. I think you should clarify what these numbers are and what is your end goal? (By end goal, I do not mean the bell curve, what I mean is that you are trying to solve some sort of problem, or come to a conclusion. Please tell us what that is, because something tells me that you want to solve X, you tried to solve it by using Y, so now you are asking about how to do that. So basically, there is a chance that this whole approach is completely wrong).